# how do I combined two adjacent lines conditioned on the sum of words of those two lines (recursive)

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I'm trying to combine two consecutive lines only if the sum of words of the two lines (words defined as consecutive characters separated by whitespaces or end of line sign) is less than 20 words.

Sample Input:

```
1This line has five words.
2This line has unfortunately six words.
3This line has also six words.
4The above three lines have a total of 18 words, which is less than 20, and should be combined into one line.
5This line has only 6 words.
```

Desired Output:

```
1This line has five words. 2This line has unfortunately six words. 3This line has also six words.
4The above three lines have a total of 18 words, which is less than 20, and should be combined into one line.
5This line has only 6 words.
```

I have the following code as a starting point, but I don't know how to make the condition so it check both consecutive lines.

```
awk '{while (sum(NF + NF+1) > 20) {sub ("\n", "")}}1'
```

Two problem is this **while (sum(NF + NF+1) > 20)**...how do I make it check the sum of two consecutive lines?
Second problem...for some reason **sub ("\n", "")** doesn't get rid of new line character at end of line, even when I try it in a single line.

Thanks.

Comment: You've stated that you want to join '2 lines', but the first line of the desired output is the combination of '3 lines' ... could you clarify either the description or the desired output???  why isn't there a line of output with just lines #2 and #3 concatenated?

Comment: @markp hey Mark. This is because of the recursive action (while function). So technically line 1 and 2 do join, since they are less than 20 words. But the NEWLY formed line (the combined line 1 and 2) when checked against line 3 (because of while function), also add up to less than 20 words, consequently it is also concatenated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk reads its input line by line, and there is no way to know the number of fields (*words* in your terms) in the next line without reading it. So, your logic won't work.

Below is a straightforward way of accomplishing this; it simply buffers lines until the word count reaches 20, releases the buffer content, and so it goes on.

```
awk '(c += NF) < 20 {
  buf = (buf sep $0)
  sep = OFS
  next
}
{
  if (NR > 1)
    print buf
  buf = $0
  c = NF
}
END {
  print buf
}' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. regarding my approach, I though awk could somehow read ahead to the next line. Now that you mentioned it read line by line, then I realize that my approach was impractical. My other thought was do use sed and utilize sed's hold space.

Comment: @HenryM I think this task is too complicated for sed. Use sed for simple text replacement and nothing else. Anyways, awk practically can read the next line using `getline` function, but it has some caveats. Take a look at http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for an elaborate explanation

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I'm taking a look at link now.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one approach by changing the **ORS** - `Output Record Separator`

```
awk 'END{printf "\n"}n<=20{ORS=FS}n>20{ORS=RS;n=0}{n+=NF}1' file
```

Comment: @Yoda thanks for the feedback but this doesn't work. Combined lines exceed the 20 word line condition.